# python to pair items from two large lists

Tags: python

I have two files:

- file1 (200mln lines) in format: email:hash1:hash2
- file2 (90mln lines) in format: hash:plaintext

What I want to do is replace hash(1 or 2) in file1 with plaintext found in file2. I tried to use solution from question I asked previously here [two lists, faster comparison in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125324/two-lists-faster-comparison-in-python) (actual code was pasted below) but unfortunately it's not that fast with such large data sets. It works well for smaller files (small amount of lines), but not with bigger ones.

What would be your suggestion to process both files 'faster'?

EDIT: source code mentioned above

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os

def banner():
    print('\n%s v 1.0\nby d2@tdhack.com\n' % sys.argv[0])

def getlength(fname):
    return sum(1 for line in open(fname))

def ifexist(fname):
    if not os.path.isfile(fname):
        banner()
        print('[-] %s must exist' % fname)
        sys.exit(1)

def replace(l, X, Y):
  for i,v in enumerate(l):
     if v == X:
        l.pop(i)
        l.insert(i, Y)

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    banner()
    print('[-] please provide CRACKED and HASHES files')
    sys.exit(1)

CRACKED=sys.argv[1]
HASHES=sys.argv[2]

ifexist(CRACKED)
ifexist(HASHES)

banner()
print('[i] preparing lists from "%s" [%d lines] and "%s" [%d lines]' %(CRACKED, getlength(CRACKED), HASHES, getlength(HASHES)))
with open(CRACKED) as crackedfile:
    cracked = dict(map(str, line.split(':', 1)) for line in crackedfile if ':' in line)

hashdata = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(HASHES)]

print('[i] pairing items, this will take a while so please be patient')
for item in hashdata:
    if item in cracked:
        replace(hashdata, item, item+':'+cracked[item].strip('\n'))

print('[i] writting changes')
fout = open(HASHES+'_paired', 'w')
for item in hashdata:
    fout.write(item+'\n')
fout.close()

print('[+] done, now check "%s" [%d lines] file for results.' % (HASHES+'_paired', getlength(HASHES+'_paired')))
```

Comment: It is better you post your code here (not pastebin)  in a minimal form to avoid getting *downvoted* and help those who will provide the answers.

Comment: tbh, I do not think there's any way of making it more efficient. You may split it over a few smaller files if memory management is the issue but regarding efficiency you can't really get any more efficient. Even SQL databases which may handle that large amount of data will slow down.

Comment: Do write to the file while iterating though, will prevent keeping some parts in memory.

Comment: Well, I tried splitting it into like 1mln lines and then process but even though the algo is slow. I wonder if 'replace' function could be an issue here? Honestly, when I look at the so called debug session, which prints modified data into screen, there is almost 1 second delay between them. Memory is not an issue here. I thought it will actually speed up things but I also realized that whole operation is single-threaded (I watched 'top' output while processing these files)

Comment: @zerocool I thought of a way to do it. Check my answer.

Comment: @Bharel I'm keep getting following error:TypeError: Expected unicode, got str

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.x

Answer (score 0):

With that many keys I would highly suggest using some sort of database with Python in order to complete your task. With a SQL database, you would have two tables that looked like this:

**emails_and_hashes**

```
column_name | column_type
----------- | ------------
email       | VARCHAR(255)
----------- | ------------
hash1       | VARCHAR(255)
----------- | ------------
hash2       | VARCHAR(255)
```

Index on `hash1` and index on `hash2`.

**hash_to_plaintext**

```
column_name | column_type
----------- | ------------
hash        | VARCHAR(255)
----------- | ------------
plaintext   | TEXT
```

Index on `hash`.

and then use a Python DB connector to iterate through the two tables and update their records in Python. This will be way faster than trying to process hundreds of millions of records in a `dict`. You could use code similar to the following (you might have to make some tweaks, this is not an *exact* answer) with this table setup, a MySQL database, and the [Python MySQL Connector library](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/):

```
import mysql.connector
con = mysql.connector.connect(user='your_user', password='your_password', database='your_database', host='your_host')
cur = con.cursor(dictionary=True) # 'dictionary=True' is my preference

# open your file with emails and hashes
f = open('/path/to/file1', 'r')
for line in f:
    email = line.split(':')[0]
    hash1 = line.split(':')[1]
    hash2 = line.split(':')[2]

    cur.execute("SELECT plaintext FROM hash_to_plaintext WHERE hash = %s", (hash1))
    plaintext1 = cur.fetchall()[0]
    cur.execute("SELECT plaintext FROM hash_to_plaintext WHERE hash = %s", (hash2))
    plaintext2 = cur.fetchall()[0]

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO emails_and_hashes VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (email, hash1, hash2))

con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I'm not that good at SQL though, could you please share some example query to achieve my goal? Also, how would you recommend to load that many records to DB?

Comment: Two questions, as I see it here a lot: 1) would 'with open .. as ...' be faster here? 2) how about using executemany?

Comment: Full disclosure: I don't know. I would maybe read into some other questions on `with...as` to see if it's faster. Same with `executemany`. I do know that this approach will be faster than just doing everything in Python.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will definitely try it.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of thinking, I came up with the idea of using a [***Trie***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

A trie will let you store that repeating hash dictionary at a much more efficient container and lookup at the same cost.

A good implementation of a Trie exists in PyPi called [marisa-trie](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/marisa-trie).

Here's an idea of mine as of how to implement it:

```
import marisa_trie
import operator

with open("file2", "rb") as myfile:
    trie = marisa_trie.BytesTrie(map(operator.methodcaller("split", b":", 1), myfile))

with open("file1", "rb") as input_file, open("modified_file1", "wb") as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        email, hash1, hash2 = line.split(b":")
        output_file.write(b":".join([email, trie[hash1], trie[hash2]]))
```

This should be fast as hell, and 50-100 times more memory efficient than a dict.

You can also store the processed trie so you won't need to recreate it every time like so:

```
trie.save('my_hashes.trie')
```

And load it like so:

```
trie = marisa_trie.BytesTrie()
trie.load('my_hashes.trie')
```

Comment: Hmm that's something new, I'll definitelly try it!